# RTesseract::ImageNotSelectedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [rtesseract](https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract) gem for my rails apps.

I'm sure, I have

- Tesseract - Program (v 3.02.02)
- ImageMagick - Program (v 6.9.0)
- image (download.png) on images directory

And  I have make the right code

```
def index
  @image = RTesseract.new(view_context.asset_path("download.png"), :processor => "none")
  @result = @image.to_s
end
```

But I got this error

```
RTesseract::ImageNotSelectedError in OcrController#index
RTesseract::ImageNotSelectedError

Extracted source (around line #4):     

  def index
    @image = RTesseract.new(view_context.asset_path("download.png"), :processor => "none")
    @result = @image.to_s
```

test on console

```
$ view_context.asset_path("download.png")
$ /assests/download.png
```

Answer (score 2):

The RTesseract only read local files and the path what you are used was a relative path to url.
Try pass the full path of file on your local server.
I guess your full path is this.

```
def index
  @image = RTesseract.new(Rails.root.join('public', 'assets','download.png').to_s, :processor => "none")
  @result = @image.to_s
end
```